# User defined variable as alias MySQL v8.0 not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

The following query (*this is a condensed form*) is running fine with user defined variables selected as an alias on `MySQL v5.6.20` BUT breaks on `MySQL v8.0.23`

```
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
        FROM q39wg_comments;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
```

Comment: It throws an error. Updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, It was happening because `rank` is now a reserved keyword in MySQL 8.x.x as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Once I updated the variable name, the query started working.

**Another alternative** is to use back-ticks which I think is more future proof as more keywords get reserved, it will prevent your SQL from breaking unnecessarily. Eg. The following works fine on MySQL v8.x.x

Eg:

```
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS `rank`
FROM q29wg_jreviews_comments ;
```

Comment: Yes, it's easiest to change the name. Or you could put `rank` in back-ticks. The manual page you linked to explains that you can use reserved words as identifiers, you just need to delimit them.

Comment: the simplest thing would be to use mysql v8's built-in ranking functions, rather than the legacy session variable trick to get the ranks of your records.

Comment: I appreaciate the advise, that would require full refactoring of code, currently we can't assign resources for that, but in longer term I totally agree we should use native features the most.

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize @rank

try this:

```
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS myrank
FROM q39wg_comments
JOIN ( SELECT @rank:=0 ) AS init;
```

see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97b2c82bac1c4c2f5008a6e5f8298e04